# Merge 2 or more inner lists

Tags: c#, list, merge

```
{
 "ProductDMList":
   [
    {
     "ProductID" : 1,
     "CabinetList":
        [
         {
          "Min" : 1,
          "Max" : 12
         }
        ]
    },
     {
     "ProductID" : 1,
     "CabinetList":
        [
         {
          "Min" : 16,
          "Max" : 100
         }
        ]
    }
   ]
}
```

I am using the below code to generate the above list.

```
List<ProductDM> productDMList = _orderRepo.GetSuggestedList(23, 12);
 for (int i=0;i<productDMList.Count;i++)
  {
   productDMList[i].CabinetList.Add(new InventoryDM {
   Min = productDMList[i].Min,
   Max = productDMList[i].Max
  });
 }

public class ProductDM
  {
    public List<InventoryDM> CabinetList { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public double Min { get; set; }
    public double Max { get; set; }
  }
public class InventoryDM
 {
    public Double Min { get; set; }
    public Double Max { get; set; }
 }
```

How can I join the above 2 lists using `ProductID`.

Ex : If the `ProductID` is same I want to create one list and bind all `cabiletLists` inside it.

Expected Output

```
{
 "ProductDMList":
   [
    {
     "ProductID" : 1,
     "CabinetList":
        [
         {
          "Min" : 1,
          "Max" : 12
         },
         {
          "Min" : 16,
          "Max" : 100
         }
        ]
     }
   ]
}
```

I tried `AddRange()` and `Concat()` methods. But I was unable to get the above expected result.

Comment: `GroupBy` is your friend

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598393/merge-2-or-more-inner-lists

Comment: You need 10000 rep to see it, it was a link to the last question that was deleted

Comment: Already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579324/how-merge-two-lists-of-different-objects Hope this helps.

Comment: @TheGeneral: The OP clearly *does not have* 10k rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this? If i understand what you are asking

```
var list = new List<ProductDM>();

var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.ProductID)
                 .Select(x => new ProductDM
                     {
                        ProductID = x.Key,
                        Min = x.Min(y => y.Min),
                        Max = x.Max(y => y.Max),
                        CabinetList = x.SelectMany(y => y.CabinetList).ToList()
                     }).ToList();
```

---

[Enumerable.GroupBy Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key
>   selector function.

Comment: What function should I use if I want to bind a string value to the above list.
Ex ; ProductID = x.Key,
                        Min = x.Min(y => y.Min),
                        Max = x.Max(y => y.Max),
                        Name= x.Max(y => y.Name),

If I want to bind the name as well to the cabinetList what function should I use. I used Min or Max. But it returns nothing to the name

Comment: How do you mean,bind a string value

Comment: Min = x.Min(y => y.Min),
                        Max = x.Max(y => y.Max),
                        Name= x.Max(y => y.Name)

If I want to bind the name as well inside the cabinet list, how I can I bind it. MIN() or MAX() functions returns `null`for the name

Comment: use the First() instead

Comment: @HarshaW    Name = x.First();

Comment: @HarshaW  Name = x.First(y => y.Name);

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use a Dictionary to access already seen Products by their ID and then add the InventoryDM instances as you loop over the un-merged List:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ProductDM> productDMList = new List<ProductDM>()
        {
            new ProductDM()
            {
                ProductID = 1,
                CabinetList = new List<InventoryDM>()
                {
                    new InventoryDM()
                    {
                        Min = 1,
                        Max = 12
                    }
                }
            },
            new ProductDM()
            {
                ProductID = 1,
                CabinetList = new List<InventoryDM>()
                {
                    new InventoryDM()
                    {
                        Min = 16,
                        Max = 100
                    }
                }
            },
        };

        Dictionary<int, ProductDM> dict = new Dictionary<int, ProductDM>();

        foreach(ProductDM product in productDMList)
        {
            if(!dict.ContainsKey(product.ProductID))
            {
                dict.Add(product.ProductID, product);
            }
            else
            {
                dict[product.ProductID].CabinetList.AddRange(product.CabinetList.ToArray());
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);

    }
```

`dict.Values` is then your merged List

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution so easy ：)

```
var tempaa = {
"ProductDMList":
    [
        {
            "ProductID": 1,
            "CabinetList":
                [
                    {
                        "Min": 1,
                        "Max": 12
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
            "ProductID": 1,
            "CabinetList":
                [
                    {
                        "Min": 16,
                        "Max": 100
                    }
                ]
        }
    ]
};

var tempbb = [];

function isExistsInBB(productId, currentProductDM, sourceCabinetList) {

  if (tempbb.length == 0) {
      tempbb.push(currentProductDM);
      return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < tempbb.length; i++) {
    var innerItem = tempbb[i];
    if (productId == innerItem.ProductID) {
        innerItem.CabinetList.push(sourceCabinetList);
    } else {
        tempbb.push(currentProductDM);
    }
  }
}

function eachTempaa() {
  for (var i = 0; i < tempaa.ProductDMList.length; i++) {
    var innerItem = tempaa.ProductDMList[i];
    isExistsInBB(innerItem.ProductID, innerItem, innerItem.CabinetList[0]);
  }
  console.log(tempbb);
}

eachTempaa();
```